# mongoDB query result with bitmap index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Does mongoDB is able to use a bitmap index or roaring bitmap index based on a filter expression or a javascript server side function that return true/false ?
I would like to boost some queries on mongoDB by having the result already pre computed and store in a bitmap index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [`SERVER-1723 Add Bitmap indexes`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1723)

This feature is in the TODO list, and this is a long TODO list...